# Plot type for illustrating before and after scores

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph, charts

Given a basic dataset like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'sid': 'SID0', 'before': .5, 'after': .8},
  {'sid': 'SID1', 'before': .6, 'after': .4},
  {'sid': 'SID2', 'before': .2, 'after': .2}
]);
# `before `has max value of 1.0; same for `after`, as these are percentages
```

[image: image of dataset]

What's a way of charting the difference between before & after scores?

Thinking to exclude the SID, and showing the distribution properly (# of students matters; not just scatter-plotting the scores). With the SID I played around with slope graphs, but that's just not good to show aggregate reflections.

Comment: What are you plotting with respect to?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I think that's part of the problem. It's not about time or anything like that. I want to visually show the improvement/detriment (difference) between student's test scores; without plotting any SIDs. - Maybe a bar chart or a point graph with each point have a radius relative to number of people with that score; and a different color for before/after.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, something just like this (Chainsmokers / Coldplay):

```
ax = df.set_index('sid').eval('diff = after - before')\
       .plot(kind='bar', alpha =1, edgecolor='black', zorder=10)
ax.grid(axis='y', color='k', alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A proposal: you may plot a line plot for each SID.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'sid': 'SID0', 'before': .5, 'after': .8},
  {'sid': 'SID1', 'before': .6, 'after': .4},
  {'sid': 'SID2', 'before': .2, 'after': .2}
]);

df = df.set_index("sid")[['before', "after"]].T

ax = df.plot(marker="o")
ax.set_xlim(-1,2)
ax.set_xticks([0,1])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)

plt.show()
```

[image]